# <ion-input> (click) opens keyboard instead of Modal

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic-framework, keyboard, modal-dialog

I have the following code in my html.

```
<ion-item (click)="showAddressModal()">
<ion-input [(ngModel)]="address.formattedAddress"
type="text" placeholder="Pick a location for your event">
</ion-input>
</ion-item>
```

showAddressModal() essentially opens a modal page where the user can search for an address.

Works like charm when I run it on chrome with ionic cordova run browser.

On ioS, however, it takes 2, sometimes 3 clicks to open the modal. First click brings the keyboard up. If I disable the keyboard by using [readonly]="true" on  then the keyboard doesn't come up, but I still need 2 clicks. If I disable the entire input using [disabled], it doesn't serve my purpose - cannot click. I have tried moving the (click) from ion-item to ion-input, I have tried removing ion-item altogether, no avail!

Please share your perspective on how I can fix this.

Regards,
J

Answer (score 0):

OK. For now, I've fixed my own problem by removing ion-input altogether and just using ion-text with a (click) listener on it. In lieu of the placeholder, I just show the same placeholder if address.formattedAddress is empty.

Still not sure where the problem is with ion-input and iOS, but will save that problem solving for another day.

For those of you, curious to see the new code, here's what the template code looks like - no change to my component or to the modal itself -

```
<ion-item (click)="showAddressModal()">
<ion-text inputmode="none">
{{ (address.formattedAddress == "") ? "Pick a location for your event" : address.formattedAddress}}
</ion-text>
</ion-item>
```

Thanks!